# Deleted Profile shows in profile management tool of IBM Websphere

Tags: websphere, websphere-7

I deleted the profile in C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\profiles and it still shows up in Profile management tool, how to delete the profile in profile management tool?

Answer (score 12):

Deleting a profile's directory is not enough; WebSphere holds additional information about profiles in its own internal directories.

The correct way to delete a profile is to use WebSphere's `manageprofiles` utility, located in `WAS_HOME/bin` (in your case: `C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\bin`). For example, if your profile's name is `MyProfile`:

```
manageprofiles -delete -profileName MyProfile
```

Comment: I tried doing that and it failed. INSTCONFAILED: Cannot delete the profile.

Comment: Also when i do this manageProfiles.bat -validateAndUpdateRegistry, it shows the output as "[]"

Comment: If `manageprofiles -listProfiles` shows nothing, and the Profile Management Tool shows that a profile exists, then one of the two: 1) WebSphere bug. Open a PMR with IBM. or 2) you have two WAS installations on this machine.

Comment: I don't have 2 WAS installations, may be its a websphere bug.

Comment: You will need to manually delete the profile under the path `C:\Program Files\IBM\SDP\runtimes\base_v7\profiles` (or similar path depending on your installation) if you got the error `INSTCONFPARTIALSUCCESS: The profile no longer exists, but errors occurred.` This happens when you don't run `manageprofiles` as Administrator.

Answer (score 2):

Let me give an elaborate answer all issues pertaining to removing profiles

Make sure you have **Full access** (Read/Write/Delete) to the `profiles` folder. Open command window as Administrator  (Shift+Right click>Run as Administrator). This will help to avoid `FileNotFoundException`. Run below command in the command window.

```
manageprofiles -delete -profileName Profilename
```

(`Profilename` is case sensitive).

If above one does not work, delete appropriate `Profile` folder manually and try below command

```
manageprofiles.bat -validateAndUpdateRegistry
```

Sometimes Windows service will remain after the removal of the profile, then run below command from  `bin` folder

```
WASService.exe -remove Nodename
```

(`Nodename` will be the last part of Service name)